# except clause in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have query like as follows.But when it is executed I am getting error message **unexpected token: except**

```
select d from DimensionStone d inner join d.stockRegister s 
where d.stockRegister.stockRegisterId <=? and s.application.applicationId=? 
and d.isIssued='No' or (s.stockRegisterId <=? and d.isIssued='Yes' 
and d.issuedDate>(select max(updatedOn) from StockRegister st 
where st.stockRegisterId<? and st.application.applicationId=?)) 
except (select d1 from DimensionStone d1 inner join d1.stockRegister s1 
where s1.stockRegisterId <=? and s1.application.applicationId=? and 
d1.isIssued='No')
```

How I can solve this problem.I have already searched enough through google.But I cannot find the desired answer.Please help me

Comment: Is `except` an HQL keyword?

Comment: i never like to write complex HQL queries. And if i do write also, i try to validate if the SQL-query generated by Hibernate is equivalent of what i intended to achive

Answer (score 0):

`except` is not a valid HQL keyword; if you want to use specific RDBMS syntax use
[`Session.createSQLQuery(String sql)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html) and a `ResultTransformer` to map every recordset row to object `DimensionStone`

Answer (score 0):

replace except with not exists:

```
select d from DimensionStone d inner join d.stockRegister s 
where d.stockRegister.stockRegisterId <=? and s.application.applicationId=? 
and d.isIssued='No' or (s.stockRegisterId <=? and d.isIssued='Yes' 
and d.issuedDate>
    (select max(updatedOn) from StockRegister st 
    where st.stockRegisterId<? and st.application.applicationId=?)) 
and not exists
    (select 'next' from DimensionStone d1 inner join d1.stockRegister s1 
    where s1.stockRegisterId <=? and s1.application.applicationId=? and 
    d1.isIssued='No')
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword EXCEPT appears to not be handled by HQL (neither MINUS), I got the same exception as you.
I achieved to reproduce the behavior of an except query using the keyword : NOT IN (NOT EXISTS might work as well)
Example:

```
SELECT a FROM MyTable a WHERE a NOT IN (SELECT a FROM MyTable a, otherTable l WHERE l.id = ?1 AND l.myObject.id = a.id)
```